# How much memory do I use exactly and how can I optimize it?

Tags: configuration, webserver, vps, virtualmin

I installed and I configured virtualmin on my 2GB RAM, 40 GB SSD, 2CPU VPS.

I currently have 5 virtual hosts (5 domains hosted). On three of them there are no files uploaded, so just two websites are working actually.

On the virtualmin admin I see some info related to memory, but in the terminal it looks different.

Does it looks ok to you guys?

What should I do in order to optimize everything and lower memory usage?

Related to swap (virtual memory), when is this going to be used?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, the virtualmin shows you the memory used by applications.
You are using 1887kk of ram, but there is a cache of 951kk. Calculating this, I see you have 936kk used, that's almost the same as the 2 minutes old value of virtualmin says.
Linux uses free memory for cache, to improve performance.
I'd say, your system is ok!

Virtual memory is beeing used if your system is out of free memory [Swapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging#Terminology)

Comment: So overall you think the system is Ok and I don't need a RAM resize?

Comment: Should I clear that cache, or this is good for the system stability ?

Comment: Just do nothing, everything is okay. Cache is always good, because it keeps a copy of files on the harddrive in memory, which is 100 times faster. You would only have to worry if the `buffer` raises extremely, which would tell you that the harddrive cannot write fast enough.

Comment: Maybe you have watched applications starting faster when started the second time after booting? That's the effort of cache.